# Oracle text index on table with conditional data from another table

Tags: oracle, indexing, full-text-search

### Situation

I'm storing **versioned files** in an Oracle database.
Each **file** has a number of **versions** (each having a distinct version number, which gets increased with each new version), and each version points to a **binary data** record, constituting the file version's content.

Tables (simplified):

```
STORAGE_FILE
- ID    NUMBER(19)

STORAGE_FILE_VERSION
- STORAGE_FILE_ID   NUMBER(19) -> references STORAGE_FILE(ID)
- DATA_ID   NUMBER(19) -> references BINARY_DATA(ID)

BINARY_DATA
- ID    NUMBER(19)
- DATA  BLOB
```

### Problem

To search within the files, I want to create an Oracle **text index**, but **only on the latest version of each file**.
The index should belong to the `STORAGE_FILE`, containing the indexed referenced `BINARY_DATA.data` from the `STORAGE_FILE_VERSION` with the latest (biggest) version.

Using the following query (for which I also created a View), I can determine the latest version and data for each file:

```
select latest_file_version.ID, latest_file_version.VERSION, b.data from (
  select f.ID, max(v.VERSION) as version from STORAGE_FILE f
  join STORAGE_FILE_VERSION v on v.STORAGE_FILE_ID = f.ID
  group by f.ID
) latest_file_version
join STORAGE_FILE_VERSION v 
    on v.STORAGE_FILE_ID = latest_file_version.ID and v.VERSION = latest_file_version.VERSION
join BINARY_DATA b on b.ID = v.DATA_ID
```

Oracle offers several [datastore types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cdatadic.htm#i1006307) for text indexes, but I'm not sure which one would be appropriate for my scenario:

- **USER_DATASTORE** allows to provide the content for the index using a user-defined stored procedure, which (I suppose) would work, but seems like an overkill, and I'd rather avoid adding a stored procedure if I can avoid it.
- **DETAIL_DATASTORE** allows the indexed column and the data column to be on separate tables. It's not clear to me if I can somehow employ this mechanism to indirectly index the binary data of the lastest version.

The other data stores don't seem to fit this problem either.
Any advice on how to realize such an index *without* falling back to materialized views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with the `USER_DATASTORE` turned out to work really well:

First, we need an **indexing column** on the `STORAGE_FILE` (to flag records for indexing, and to run Oracle text queries against it):

```
alter table STORAGE_FILE add INDEX_FLAG char(1) default 'Y';
```

A **procedure** is needed to **provide the blob for the index**. Here we want to determine the latest file version using the view (query as in question):

```
create or replace procedure STORAGE_FILE_DATA 
(rid in rowid, tlob in out NOCOPY blob ) is
begin
  begin
    select data.binary_data into tlob from STORAGE_FILE f
    left outer join VW_STORAGE_FILE_DATA data on f.id=data.file_id
    where f.rowid = rid and f.INDEX_FLAG='Y';
  exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then tlob := null;
  end;
end;
/
```

Next, we create the **index** (and **preferences**) which employs the procedure above:

```
begin
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('FILE_DATA_DATASTORE','user_datastore');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('FILE_DATA_DATASTORE','procedure','STORAGE_FILE_DATA');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('FILE_DATA_DATASTORE','output_type','blob_loc');
end;
/

create index INDEX_FILE_DATA
on STORAGE_FILE (INDEX_FLAG)
indextype is ctxsys.context
parameters ('filter ctxsys.auto_filter
             datastore FILE_DATA_DATASTORE
             memory 200M
             transactional')
/
```

Also, we need a **trigger** to flag entries for re-indexing once they are changed:

```
create or replace trigger TRIGGER_INDEX_FILE
before update on STORAGE_FILE
for each row
begin
  :new.INDEX_FLAG := 'Y';
end;
/
```

And we're done. Now we can run full-text queries on the lastest file versions' data only:

```
select * from STORAGE_FILE f
where contains (f.INDEX_FLAG, 'Hello AND World', 1) > 0;
```